# How to insert the second record in a Temp Table?

Tags: forms, axapta, temp-tables, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

In my form I used a Temporary Table in DataSource - with property **TableType: InMemory** .

In My form I have a simple code,like this:

```
public TableTmpTable insertRecords(String _param_I, string _param_II)
{ 
  TableTmpTable myInMemoryTable;

  myInMemoryTable.clear();
  myInMemoryTable.initValue();

  myInMemoryTable.Field_I =  _param_I;
  myInMemoryTable.Field_II = _param_II;

  myInMemoryTable.insert();

  return myInMemoryTable;
}
```

I need to call this method more than once.

But, whenI call the method I lost my previous record.
How can insert more record in **InMemory** table in different time?

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Scope**
>
> An InMemory table is instantiated when the first record is inserted. The instantiated InMemory table continues to exist only while a record buffer variable that references the table exists. The memory or disk space for the InMemory table is de-allocated as soon as the record buffer goes out of scope.

From MSDN, [Temporary InMemory Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb314749.aspx)

What your code does is it creates a new instance of the table buffer each time the method is called. Instead, you need to use the table buffer of the form data source.

See also  [Temporary table as form data source](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/165150) and [AX 2012: Using Temporary Table as Form’s Datasource](https://dynamicsaxinsight.wordpress.com/2014/08/20/ax-2012-using-temporary-table-as-forms-datasource/)

Comment: Thanks @FH-Inway . Very helpful advice.
I declared the InMemoryTable only one time in Form's classDeclaration my Table and used it in all process.

Answer (score 0):

just split your method from one to two.

The first method will initialize your table and the second will insert your records.

Comment: OP mentioned in the comments that she initialized the table in the form's `classDeclaration`. What would your initialization method do in addition to that?